# Prepare an JSON data request for stream data type

Tags: c#, json

How to prepare an JSON data for below request :

Trying out the below formed json data request but throws bad request error:

```
{
    "filename":"test.txt",
    "fileContent": "eyJtZW51IjogewogICJpZCI6ICJmaWxlIiwKICAidmFsdW"
}
```

> ServiceCall contract:

```
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
                   UriTemplate = "/fileuploader/upload",
                   BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
                   RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
                   ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
 Stream LoadFile(string fileName, Stream fileContent);
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to create a `DataContract` for the request as it is a complex object(*i.e. more than 1 property.*) Or change the `steam` object to `string` type and then in the Method convert the `string` to `bytes[]`.

Comment: thats what there for me to use , i cannot change that , yeah though i can create new my requirement is to pass filecontent and file name.  What i thought to pass file path and file name but want to keep this as last option

Comment: have a look at [WCF upload File(stream)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37542637/2417602).